# Texmaker doesn't work with XeLatex (but everything else does)

Tags: xetex, miktex, texmaker, editors

I have Miktex 2.96821 and I want to move from using pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX compiler. I have been using Texmaker (v. 5.04) for most of the time, and I want to hold on to this editor, however, it doesn't produce the output when the XeLaTeX compiler is selected (please note, that there have been no issues with pdfLatex or Bib(La)TeX).

---

**The Error**

Once I select
*Preferences -> Texmaker configuration -> Quick Build-> XeLaTeX + pdf preview*,

four error boxes appear sequentially with the following messages:

> Log file not found!
>
> Log file not found!
>
> File not found
>
> Log file not found!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[small,sf,bf]{titlesec}

\setromanfont{Georgia}
\setsansfont{Tahoma}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

---

On the other hand, I can successfully compile this source file with either Texworks or command line `xelatex example.tex`

**How can I compile tex file with XeLaTex using TexMaker?**

Remarks:

1. I re-installed TexMaker and it didn't help
2. I have default commands under `pdfLatex` and `XeLaTeX` lines in *Preferences -> Texmaker configuration -> Commands*:

   - For  *XeLaTeX + pdf preview*: `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
   - For *pdfLatex*: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Comment: Go to the `Quick Build` configuration and select `xelatex`. B.t.w., present version of MiKTeX is 7560. Would be time to update (unrelated, though).

Comment: That's what I'm doing: *Preferences -> Texmaker configuration -> Quick Build -> XeLaTeX + pdf preview*, though I gave it wrong name while translating from my native language. I edited the question to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Strange… I have absolutely no problem (I'm under Windows 7, usually use another editor, but keepTeXmaker just in case.).

Comment: Yeah, I also reinstalled MikTeX, also to na avail. I have this bug only on one of my PC's. Neverthe less, the only fix was to switch to other editor, in tyhis acase TexStudio (it has prettier GUI anyway ;p ).

Comment: Had the same issue and it transpies that texlive-xetex is not installed.